# AFNetworking converting my String values to integers while returning JSON?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

I have created a rest service whose output is of the form

```
 {
        "id": "1905",
        "groupId": "724",
        "giftingId": null,
        "name": "This is a great service",
   }
```

I am using AFNetworking http client to call this service. Its output is

```
  {
     name = "This is a great service";
     id = 1905;
     groupId = 724;
     giftingId = "<null>";
  }
```

I am unable to parse that gifting id when its null. I simply want to parse the data to NSString? Why is it parsing the JSON as integers when they are sent as strings?

Comment: What JSON library are you using along with AFNetworking? AFN support multiple third-party JSON-parsing library (including the build-in `NSJSONSerialization` class embedded in iOS5+ but not exclusively), and the result you have will obviously depend on the JSON library used (as some libraries try to guess and convert the result type).

Comment: I haven't specified anywhere to use a particular JSON library. I guess its the iOS 5 built-in functionality...

Comment: Yes if you don't link with any 3rd-party JSON lib then it will use the build-in one on iOS5. And your application won't work on iOS4 (it will crash at runtime when it will try to parse the JSON). AFN automatically detect if some JSON libraries it knows (JSONKit, SBJSON, etc) is linked against the application, and uses it if it is, giving you the ability to use AFN and JSON even in apps compatible with iOS4 that don't have `NSJSONSerialization` yet. Of course if `NSJSONSerialization` is available, e.g. the user runs your app in iOS5+, it uses this in priority.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what you are seeing in the output. When an NSDictionary is output, it doesn't print double quotes for any string that is all letters and number. `This is a great service` has spaces and `<null>` has angle brackets.

I'm pretty sure that the dictionary which prints as:

```
{
    name = "This is a great service";
    id = 1905;
    groupId = 724;
    giftingId = "<null>";
}
```

is actually:

```
@{
    @"name" : @"This is a great service",
    @"id" : @"1905",
    @"groupId" : @"724",
    @"giftingId" : [NSNull null],
}
```

I think the solution here is handling and detecting the NSNull. `[JSON[@"giftingId"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]` should be able to detect if `giftingId` is an NSNull.

If you don't have the lastest Xcode, then you should use `[[JSON objectForKey:@"giftingId"] isEqual:[NSNull null]]`